# If Views Cannot Be Shared Then How Should the View Id Be Allocated?

Tags: android, android-layout

FYI Views in Android cannot be shared, this is a debatable sdk design decision, but thats the way it is. Each view can have at most one parent view.  However in order for a layout to serve as a view template, a common view_layout.xml file can be reused (ie inflated several times).  What are the implications for the viewid and the id of elements within the view such as buttons.

- Should these not be defined inside the view_layout.xml? (eg so that there are not for example two buttons with the same id albeit in different view instances).
- what about the instance id of the view itself?
- How are these views to be uniquely defined given the common view_layout.xml file?
- Of course you can have separate references to the views inflated but what about the id of the view itself and the widgets inside it?

Comment: Try reading it.  That's the best way to understand it.

Comment: Oh my gosh I really missed that... read it, still: What is your question? You are stating facts, but no real question. And stop being rude again, would you? We both had that some weeks ago...

Comment: Well lets just wait and see if someone understands it ....

Comment: "this is a debatable sdk design decision" I disagree. Imagine if every row in a ListView used the same instance of one Button. When the user clicks _any_ row _every_ Button would be clicked. Each row needs a unique copy of the Button to discern which Button was actually clicked.

Comment: Sam see Flex SDK for more possibilites of view sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what *exactly* you are trying to address here, but Views in a layout should never clash if you designed your layouts properly. View Ids apply only to the direct parent ViewGroup. Suppose you have ViewGroup **A** and it is your top level ViewGroup. You then inflate two instances of ViewGroup **B** and add then to **A**, their respective Ids will not clash as they have no reference of eachother. Their scopes are completely different.